# check which activity is launched in android device

Tags: android

I want to lock apps with a password activity.  I have an app in which I get current the foreground activity class name using this code:

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager
    = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> list = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = list.get(0);
String activityName = ar.topActivity.getClassName();
Toast.makeText(this,activityName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I want to run this code whenever any app is launched.  How can I do that?

Comment: Note that `getRunningTasks()` is deprecated in the "L" developer preview and should remain deprecated in the next Android release. It will only return tasks associated with your own app.

Comment: then what is the solution to solve this problem?? i want to show my lock screen when user open the gallery...